# using Array Values at Sql Parameters in C#

Tags: c#, sql, arrays, parameters

I'm developing a bureau program in c#. I want to write database an array value binding `SqlParameter` like this;

```
NUMBEROFDOCUMENT         DEPT         STATION
----------------------------------------------
      13                 BT           OPEN
      13                 DY           OPEN
      13                 AC           OPEN
```

So how can I add multiple rows (what the numbers of array length) just with one command?

```
kmt.parameters.addwithvalue("@DEPT", deptArray[i])
```

Comment: You mean something like this `where dept in ('BT','DY','AC')`?

Comment: If you mean so then "NO"; either create a stored procedure to handle that (OR) create separate parameter for each value (OR) join all the value like a inlist and use it as parameter.

Comment: @Rahul He actually can use TVPs:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never messed with them, but have you tried using Table-Valued Parameters?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you can use ArrayList/ List and you can loop through the List